# WP Thumbail not rendered correctly

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to add a thumbail to a div using `the_post_thumbnail()` function.

The code I'm using is the following:

```
<div class="sc-col sc-s12 sc-m3 sc-card sc-card-basic">
    <figure>'.the_post_thumbnail(array('370', '188')).'</figure>
</div>
```

But when the code is rendered in a browser the code becomes (*just took a part of the rendered code*):

```
<img width="370" height="182" src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/image.png">
<div class="sc-col sc-s12 sc-m3 sc-card sc-card-basic">
    <figure></figure>
</div>
```

As you can see the image is rendered outside the `div` and `figure`. My question is why is it doing this? Because now my whole layout is breaking now and, the problem is that I have to use that function else I would have used an other function. Can I somehow rewrite the function so it only returns the src link using `add_filter` function?

Comment: you need to wrap the function in php tags

Comment: @DhavalChheda That ofcourse is something I have done. The tags are before this because I don't like to open and close every line of php. Should I just use `<figure><?php the_post_thumbnail(array('370', '188')); ?></figure>`? Which I would find very strange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved it for me:

```
<figure><?php the_post_thumbnail(array('370', '188')); ?></figure>
```

As staded by @ChrisLear `the_post_thumbail()` doens't return a string and there for fails.

Comment: It doesn't fail exactly. It echos to the output stream.

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail/ shows that the function `the_post_thumbnail` is designed to actually output something to the page, not return a string.

So change your code to something more like this:

```
$html = '<div class="sc-col sc-s12 sc-m3 sc-card sc-card-basic">
    <figure>';
echo $html;
the_post_thumbnail(array('370', '188'))
$html = '</figure>
</div>';
echo $html;
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up for the function not returning a string. There for I went with open and closing php for the required part. Altough I have come across this before in WP I still find it a bit strange. They reason I went for that solution is because it's a bit shorter and is easier to read.